# How to fix "Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord

how can I fix this?I want to create PING command

error: client.commands.get('ping').run(message, args)
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Here is my ping code

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping', 
    description: "this is a ping command!",
    execute(message, args){


        
        message.channel.send('pong!');    
   }
}
```

Also here is my index.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client  = new Discord.Client();

const prefix = '-';

const fs = require('fs');

client.command = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
  for(const file of commandFiles){
     const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
       
       client.command.set(command.name, command);

  }

client.once('ready', () => {


    console.log('MuriCraft is online!');
});

client.on('message', Message => {
       if (!Message.content.startsWith(prefix) || Message.author.bot) return;
       const args  = Message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
       const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

       if(command === 'ping'){
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
    }
})


client.login('!Hiden!');
```

Comment: client.command vs client.commands maybe? in index.js you define client.command but later call client.commands.get, and commands would be undefined.

Comment: this is not working.

Comment: Well, any details on how you tried to fix it?

Comment: i just edit commands to command

Answer (score 1):

Its very small command, so you can include it in your Main/Index.js file

```
if(msg.content === '!ping'){
   msg.channel.send('Pong!;)
```